# Replicate Android Home Grid View

Tags: java, android, gridview, touch

Are there any projects or libraries on the web that 'replicate' the android home screen? Or if not can anyone point in the right direction of trying to replicate it.

What im trying to do is have a grid view and being able to hold my finger on a item and then move it around so that it would slot in to between 2 other items, like what you can do on the Android Home Screen, you are able to move each icon on a grid.

Any help would be much appreciated. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the source code of the android platform. look for the launcher classes. also there is a sample in the sdk samples about creating a homescreen app. you might start from there.